# With a javascript dynamic variable, how to initialize slide/change event on jQuery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have:
a GLOBAL, DYNAMIC variable:

`var index=0;`

an array:

`var arr={ 1:"First", 2:"Second" };`

a function:

`var UpdateFunc=function(value){ arr[index]=value; };`

Now I have a jQuery slider with slider event initialized as below:

`$("#slider").slider({ change: function(evt, ui){ UpdateFunc(ui.value); } });`

In some case, before sliderchange invoked, VARIABLE index is changed, but as debugging, UpdateFunc invoked through sliderchange, is always 0 (the first time appending).

So my question is: How to initialize slide / change event of jQuery slider DYNAMICALLY, such as with dynamic variable index in this case ?

Thanks and hope to get your responses soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [value method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#methods)

```
$('#slider').slider("value", 100);
```

Comment: Thanks Calum. But what I meant is I want slide/change event of slider, when being invoked, affects on the right arr[index], with global index is changed and changed dynamically. Slider value is not my attention.

Comment: Oh. I didn't understand your question. You can just put arr[index] = ui.value; in the change function

Comment: It does work. However, you'll only ever get arr[0] = x since you never change the index var. What are the other values in arr supposed to be doing?

Comment: However, you'll only ever get arr[0] = x since you never change the index var.

That's the issue Calum, because I wanna modify this arr[] times after times, as a global variable